# Search string, but allow different but similar punctuation characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring, string-comparison

I want to search a string for a substring, but allow for differing but similar punctuation characters (including spaces).

For example, if I have the string

```
@"this is a 'difficult' string to search"
```

and I search for the substring

```
@"a ‘difficult‘ string"
```

it will not currently be found, because the substring uses different types of single quotes.

Is there a way of searching that allows for slight variations such as this? Or do I have to write my own way? And if I have to write my own way, how do I go about it?

Obviously there are many other possibilities that I want to cover, there are a number of types of:

double quotes (e.g. U+0022, U+201C, U+201D)

single quotes (U+0027, U+2018, U+2019)

dashes (U+002D, U+2010, U+2011, U+2012, U+2013, U+2014, U+2015 (etc))

spaces (U+0020, U+00A0 (etc))

etc

So how can I do something like

```
[myString rangeOfString:subString options:allowForSimilarPunctuation]
```

So far I have been altering the string and substring by replacing combinations of characters and doing repetitious searches, but this seems a clumsy way, there must be a clever way of doing this?

Comment: I'd strip both strings of all non-alphanumeric characters and non-spaces. Then do the comparison.

Comment: Yes, I was going to state in the question that I had tried that, but this method also gives positive matches when punctuation is not very similar. I'd like it to be more accurate than that. I suppose I could replace all spaces with "normal" spaces, and all double quotes with one type of double quotes etc.. This would work, but it seems a bit clumsy, I'd like to know how to do it "properly"

Answer (score 1):

You can use character classes:

```
@"a [‘']difficult[‘'] string"
```

Here's an example on Regex101 if you want to give it a whirl:
https://regex101.com/r/iZ6lQ8/1

Comment: interesting, I didn't know this was a possibility. It would still mean creating a new version of the substring, which still feels a bit clumsy, but it does seem better than what I am currently doing (assuming it works :) ). I could just create a category on NSString. I'll give this a go if I don't get any other options in the next few minutes.

Comment: Cool. I provided a link to an online testing tool for the expression if you wanted to get your hands dirty with that approach.

Comment: Thanks, I've given you votes up, but I'm going to put my answer with code in as the accepted answer, so other people can use it too :)

Comment: Actually I deleted my answer, because I ended up needing to add too much ad hoc code, and it didn't seem an elegant answer anymore.